# What is OBS iPod Touch

Tags: ipod-touch

Today I found an old iPod Touch and it seems like something is wrong with it so I boot it into recovery mode and try to restore it with iTunes. But there are something wrong and I have to manually restore it with the IPSW file. Now I am at [ipsw.me](http://ipsw.me) and stuck while trying to identify what device this is. I went to [checkcoverage.apple.com](http://checkcoverage.apple.com) and enter my iPod Touch's serial number. It tells me it is OBS iPod Touch. Here's the result:

[image: Check coverage result]

Here's a picture of the iPod Touch if it helps:

[image: iPod Touch]

Comment: "Obsolete", which I guess isn't really that helpful :/ iTunes ought to be able to find the correct ipsw for it, btw. & telling us what the "something wrong" is may help too.

Comment: @Tetsujin Good guess:) This iPod can only boot to recovery. When I plug it into iTunes, it just says iPod. I think it is attempting to download iOS 3.1.3 but it can't.

Comment: well, only Touch whose last iOS is 3.1.3 is the original, 1st gen, so that might narrow it down a bit ;-)